# Where can I find good examples for 2d games in MonoTouch?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I searched on mono touch page but there are not much graphics examples. Could someone point me to some introductory graphics in mono touch?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout [XnaTouch](http://xnatouch.codeplex.com/).  They have samples that you can run on the device and sim.  I'd recommend pulling the source code from the repository as the last zipped version of the framework is from Dec '09.